# Break line in view from list in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a List containing string objects that should be displayed in the view. But i have problems getting the output correctly. In the list there are words like Computer, Screen, Mouse. Now it´s displayed like `ComputerScreenMouse` and want it displayed like

`Computer`

`Screen`

`Mouse`

I´ve checked the object during run-time and it´s adding the strings correctly like

`[0] Computer
 [1] Screen
 [2] Mouse`

This is the code that I´m using

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.MyParts, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })
```

I've tried a couple different stuff with foeach loops but nothing seems to work. If i use the @Html.Raw and put in a br tag it prints out the list like this:

`ComputerScreenMouse 
 ComputerScreenMouse 
 ComputerScreenMouse`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyParts)
{

    @Html.Raw(Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.MyParts, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } }) + "</br>")
}
```

The model looks like this. In the view I´m using `@modelGlossary_mvc.Models.Parts`

```
public class DoTestModel
{
    public string Stuff{ get; set; }
    public string OtherStuff { get; set; }
    public List<Parts> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class Parts
{
    public List<string> MyParts{ get; set; }
    public List<string> SpareParts{ get; set; }
    public int NumberOfParts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try an unordered list ?
Just try it like

 <ul style="list-style: none;">
 // your for loop here
 // each item as <li>
 //close for loop
 </ul>

Comment: What does your HTML wrapper look like, How are you displaying this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are wrapping your output in HTML will depend on the outcome. Are you using this in a form? as i generally only use form-control for fields.

Since your output is not HTML you need to try this if you need the form-control.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.MyParts)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })
<br />
}
```

Without form-control to just display the list:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyParts)
    {
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item )
    <br />
    }
```

And depending how you have your HTML wrapper you may or may not need the `<br />`

Comment: Oh it was this "simple"...Thank you and thanks to James for posting the answer first.

Answer (score 1):

`Display(For)` / `Editor(For)` really aren't ideal for `List<string>` properties.  They should be reserved for specialized display and editing templates, or properties that have the `[Display]` attribute.

Your model property `MyParts` is a simple list of strings.

`public List<string> MyParts{ get; set; }`

Keep it simple, output each string (e.g. in an un-ordered list):

```
<ul>
@foreach(var part in Model.MyParts)
{
    <li>@part</li>
}
</ul>
```

Ok, but what if the `MyParts` property is a list of `PartModel` objects?  This is where the MVC `DisplayFor` / `EditorFor` shines.

**PartModel**

```
public class PartModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
// your view model
public class Parts
{
    // now a list of PartModels not strings
    public List<PartModel> MyParts{ get; set; }
    public List<string> SpareParts{ get; set; }
    public int NumberOfParts { get; set; }
}
```

**Razor View**

```
@model Parts

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyParts)
```

**Display Template for PartModel**

```
@model PartModel
<div>
    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</span>
    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Quantity)</span>
</div>
```

This file can be located in couple places.  It's up to you based on how much you need to share it throughout the project:

1. \Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\PartModel.cshtml
2. \Views\\DisplayTemplates\PartModel.cshtml